# Add multiple values to one registry key

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I add multiple values to one registry key without having to repeat `REG ADD [key]` on every line?

Comment: What type of the value in that registry? If you want multiple string add this `reg add /T "REG_MULTI_SZ" /V "value1 value 2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to avoid having to retype the key:

```
Set "Key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"
Reg Add "%Key%" /f /v CompletionChar      /t REG_DWORD /d 0x9
Reg Add "%Key%" /f /v DelayedExpansion    /t REG_DWORD /d 0x0
Reg Add "%Key%" /f /v EnableExtensions    /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1
Reg Add "%Key%" /f /v PathCompletionChar  /t REG_DWORD /d 0x9
reg add "%key%" /f /v DefaultColor        /t REG_DWORD /d 0x0a
```